# Remove one voice from a video?

Tags: audio, video, removal

My close friends husband died last weekend.  I came a across a video I took of him singing her favorite song but I'm singing pretty loudly also.  Is it possible to remove my voice or at least make it less loud?  When I showed her the video she cried and had just thought yesterday that she would never get to hear him sing that song to her again.  This would be such a gift for her.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is unlikely to be possible with current technology.

In the past few years, removing a voice from a music track has turned from pipe-dream into reality, using machine learning techniques [often mislabelled Artificial Intelligence].
Removing one voice from another singing in unison or even harmony though, is a whole different level of "AI".

If the voices are on different sides of a stereo file, then you could possibly separate the stereo & process just one side. I'm assuming this is a phone recording with a mono soundtrack, which I think is currently an unreachable goal.

Answer (score 0):

sorry to hear that :/

I don't think you could do this automaticly with AI, but of course you can edit the audio with EQ and loudness automations to at least make your parts less obvious or loud. Afterwards just render a new video with the new soundfile.

If you don't have the tools to do it, I surely could help you out with that :)
My friend makes animated videos and I cut the sounds to his videos so it would be no big deal I gues. Peace